# Postgres SELECT a concat field and ILIKE it in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Pretty simple, trying to do this

```
 SELECT  (artist_name || ' ' || name) as full_name FROM "songs"  WHERE "songs"."working" = 't' AND (full_name ILIKE('%Jack Beats%')) AND (full_name ILIKE('%Epidemic%')) AND (full_name ILIKE('%Dillon Francis%')) ORDER BY songs.published_at asc LIMIT 1
```

But I get

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "full_name" does not exist
```

I've tried adding the table name before the stations with no effect.

Comment: Because you cannot use named aliases for a column directly in where clause. It should come from a sub-query.

Answer (score 11):

As sub_stantial mentions in the comments, you can't reference an alias from a SELECT in your WHERE clause. You can use a derived table as dwurf suggests but derived tables in Rails are a bit messy. You could expand your concatenation inside your WHERE instead:

```
Song.where(:working => true)
    .where("artist_name || ' ' || name ILIKE ?", '%Jack Beats%')
    .where("artist_name || ' ' || name ILIKE ?", '%Epidemic%')
    .where("artist_name || ' ' || name ILIKE ?", '%Dillon Francis%')
    .order('songs.published_at asc')
    .limit(1)
```

And if you're doing this sort of thing a lot, a named scope might be useful:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
    #...
    def self.full_name_like(name)
        where("artist_name || ' ' || name ILIKE ?", "%#{name}%")
    end
end
```

and then:

```
Song.where(:working => true)
    .full_name_like('Jack Beats')
    .full_name_like('Epidemic')
    .full_name_like('Dillon Francis')
    .order('songs.published_at asc')
    .limit(1)
```

If your application is going to be doing a lot of ILIKE searches like this then you might want to look into a full-text search system: LIKE queries lead to table scans and table scans lead to sadness.

Answer (score 2):

You can't reference a column alias in a where clause. The correct way to write this query is:

```
SELECT  
  (artist_name || ' ' || name) AS full_name 
FROM "songs"  
WHERE "songs"."working" = 't' 
AND ((artist_name || ' ' || name) ILIKE('%Jack Beats%')) 
AND ((artist_name || ' ' || name) ILIKE('%Epidemic%'))
AND ((artist_name || ' ' || name) ILIKE('%Dillon Francis%'))
ORDER BY songs.published_at ASC
limit 1
;
```

sub_stantial's approach would look more like this:

```
select full_name 
from (
    SELECT  
        (artist_name || ' ' || name) AS full_name 
    FROM "songs"  
    WHERE "songs"."working" = 't' 
    ORDER BY songs.published_at ASC
)
WHERE (full_name ILIKE('%Jack Beats%')) 
AND (full_name ILIKE('%Epidemic%'))
AND (full_name ILIKE('%Dillon Francis%'))
LIMIT 1
;
```

Performance of these two queries is about the same (pretty rubbish) as they both have to do a full table scan to build the full_name column then sort the results. You might be able to add an index to "working" to speed up these queries.

Here's an [sql fiddle in postgresql](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/27bc8/2)

Answer (score 0):

Programatic Arel version

*NOTE: This has not been fully tested for SQL injection.*

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :fields_sentence_ilike, -> (*fields, term) {
    sanitized_term = connection.quote("%#{term}%")

    # InfixOperation.new(operator, left, right) => left operator right => concatenated_fiels ILIKE '%word%'
    # NamedFunction.new(name, expression_nodes) => name(node0, node1, ...nodeN) => CONCAT_WS("columnA", "columnB", "columnC")
    where(
      Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new(
        Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new('ILIKE'),
        Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
          'CONCAT_WS', # CONCAT_WS concatenates strings using the first argument. In this case, an empty space.
          [
            Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("' '"), # CONCAT by empty space
            *fields.map { |field|
              # CONCATING any NULL fields results NULL (like multiplying any number by 0 equals 0). COALESCE to empty string.
              Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('COALESCE', [arel_attribute(field), Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("''")])
            }
          ]
        ),
        Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new(sanitized_term)
      )
    )
  }
end
```

Then a specific implementation for your Songs model

```
class Song < ApplicationRecord
  scope :full_name_like, -> (full_name) { fields_sentence_ilike(:artist_name, :name, full_name) }
end
```

Usage

```
Song.full_name_like('Jack Beats')
  .full_name_like('Epidemic')
  .full_name_like('Dillon Francis')
```