# How to ignore symbols using the LIKE feature in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I know the `LIKE` is an SQL command so i'll add SQL in also

Basically i have this command

```
gigurldb = Gigtable.where('eventtitle ILIKE ? AND eventdoortime = ? ', "%#{tmname}%", "#{tmdate}").first
```

What happens is `tmname` passes through the name

```
Granny Smiths - Apples
```

Whereas in the `Gigtable` its saved in the `eventtitle` column as this

```
Granny Smiths : Apples
```

Now this isn't being picked up by the `LIKE` or `ILIKE` methods.

Any ideas how i can get away with making this work?

Thanks

Comment: One possible solution is Postgres "Full text search". it is somewhat complex, but it covers your case (and much more).

Answer (score 0):

The `ILIKE` code which is helpful only for the non case sensitive operations only.But in this scenario, replaces - with : is not accepted by `ILIKE`. `ILIKE` works only when `Granny Smiths - Apples` match to `granny smiths - Apples` scenarios. please follow the link  for further details 
[Postgres SELECT a concat field and ILIKE it in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678663/postgres-select-a-concat-field-and-ilike-it-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

If the problem character in question is always a colon or hyphen, you could replace colons & hyphens in your search string with a wildcard.

```
gigurldb = Gigtable.where('eventtitle ILIKE ? AND eventdoortime = ? ', "%#{tmname.gsub(/[\-\:]/,"%")}%", "#{tmdate}").first
```

This will generate sql like

```
eventtitle ILIKE '%Granny Smiths % Apples%'
```

which will catch both cases.